# Performance of iterating a list by recursively examining the tail

Tags: performance, haskell, recursion, clojure

I decided to try to learn Haskell by doing some of the [CodinGame](https://www.codingame.com) challenges (so this question is super beginner-level stuff I'm sure). One of them requires searching through a list of integers for the smallest difference between any two values. I've previously solved it in Clojure by doing this:

```
(ns Solution
  (:gen-class))

(defn smallest-difference [values]
  (let [v (sort values)]
    (loop [[h & t] v curr-min 999999]
      (if (nil? t) curr-min
        (let [dif (- (first t) h)]
          (recur t (if (> curr-min dif) dif curr-min)))))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (let [horse-strengths (repeatedly (read) #(read))]
      (let [answer (smallest-difference horse-strengths)]
        (println answer))))
```

I tried to implement the same solution in Haskell, with the following:

```
readHorses :: Int -> [Int] -> IO [Int]
readHorses n h
    | n < 1 = return h
    | otherwise = do
        l <- getLine
        let hn = read l :: Int
        readHorses (n - 1) (hn:h)

findMinDiff :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
findMinDiff h m
    | (length h) < 2    = m
    | (h!!1 - h!!0) < m = findMinDiff (tail h) (h!!1 - h!!0)
    | otherwise         = findMinDiff (tail h) m



main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering -- DO NOT REMOVE
    input_line <- getLine
    let n = read input_line :: Int
    hPrint stderr n
    horses <- readHorses n []
    hPrint stderr "Read all horses"
    print (findMinDiff (sort horses) 999999999)
    return ()
```

This times-out for large inputs (99999 values) where the Clojure solution does not. They look pretty similar to me however.

It at least superficially seems that reading the values and constructing the list isn't the problem, as "Read all horses" is printed before the timeout.

How can I make the Haskell version more performant?

Comment: `length h < 2` will traverse the whole list. I'd use pattern matching instead for `[]` and `[_]`, even if this require a minor duplication. (In the last case, I'd use `(x1:x2:xs)` and avoid the partial `!!` -- this does not improve speed but it is way more idiomatic)

Comment: Thanks! I'd definitely appreciate an example implementation of findMindDiff that illustrates this @chi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calculating the `length` of the list in every recursion into `findMinDiff`. Since [`length`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:length) takes `O(n)` time `findMinDiff` takes `O(n^2)` time instead of `O(n)`.

You can write the same thing with [pattern matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) instead of `length`, `!!`, and `tail`

```
findMinDiff :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
findMinDiff (h0 : hs@(h1 : _)) m = 
    if h1 - h0 < m
    then findMinDiff hs (h1 - h0)
    else findMinDiff hs m
findMinDiff _ m = m
```

Comment: Note that `if...then...else` is just an expression, so you can factor out the functional call and first argument: `findMinDiff hs (if h1 - h0 < m then h1 - h0 else m)`. You can also replace the expression with call to `min`.

Comment: @chepner Yes, but the goal in this answer is for the code to be as similar as possible to the OPs to demonstrate the difference between guarding on length and pattern matching. If I could have written the `if ... then ... else` with guards without it being hideous I would have.

Comment: I'm sure the code works, but this syntax `(h0 : hs@(h1 : _))` terrifies/confuses me. From the link, it looks like there may be ways to do it in a more verbose but easier to follow way? Or just help me out with that syntax - what's the @ doing? Feel free to assume I'm a moron.

Comment: @Orphid the more verbose way would pattern match on `(h0 : h1 : hs')` and then reconstruct the list `h1 : hs'` for the calls to the tail. Since `h1 : hs'` is already in the pattern I'm capturing it with a new name using `hs@(h1 : hs')`, then since `hs'` isn't used anywhere replacing it with a `_`.

Comment: @Orphid You can read the pattern `h0 : hs@(h1 : _)` as "if the input list has the form `h0 : hs` (so it's nonempty) where the tail `hs` has the form `h1 : _` (again, nonempty), then proceed as follows: ...". You can then use `h0,h1,hs` in what follows with their natural meaning.

Comment: @chi Ciridec also added the line `findMinDiff _ m = m` after the function. How does that affect things?

Comment: @Orphid Yes: that line is only reached when the first pattern fails, i.e. when `length h < 2`.

Answer (score 4):

By the way, a completely alternative implementation could be written as follows. (Pseudocode follows)

Take the list

```
h = [h0, h1, h2 ...
```

Remove one element

```
drop 1 h = [h1, h2, h3 ...
```

Compute pointwise differences

```
zipWith (-) (drop 1 h) h = [h1-h0, h2-h1, h3-h2, ...
```

Then take the minimum. Full code:

```
minDiff :: [Int] -> Int
minDiff h = minimum (zipWith (-) (drop 1 h) h)
```

Note that this will crash on the empty list. On the other hand, there's no need of the `9999999` hack. Thanks to laziness, it runs in constant space, too.

For a better error handling:

```
minDiff :: [Int] -> Int
minDiff [] = error "minDiff: empty list"
minDiff h = minimum (zipWith (-) (drop 1 h) h)
```

or even, more pedantically (but respecting totality):

```
minDiff :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
minDiff [] = Nothing
minDiff h  = Just (minimum (zipWith (-) (drop 1 h) h))
```

Comment: Yes - in fact, after I completed the challenge I was able to view the solutions of others. exlevan's seems to be the top rated, and uses `minimum` and `zipWith` too.

Comment: @Orphid Knowing library functions surely can help, but as an exercise it is more important to learn to solve this without too much library help. If possible, I'd suggest to avoid `length, head, tail, !!` (and perhaps guards as well) since in many beginner's exercises they are unneeded and only lead to fragile code. It is much better, in Haskell, to prefer pattern matching to anything else.